# How to set boundaries for Primitives in Genetic Programming

Tags: genetic-programming, deap

my question is very simple. How can I set the boundaries to the primitives of a Genetic Programming Algo?

Le's make an example: I want as primitive the square root of a number, we know very well that this function has domain in [0,inf), so, how can I tell to GP Algo that it can combine that primitive only with inputs with a number major or equal to zero?

I'm currently using python and DEAP.